# How can I style specific item in a mvc dropdownlist

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-select, dropdown

I have the following code that fill a dropdownlist with values. I would like to have the text in bold if x.Level == 0. Can that be achieved or is that impossible in select lists to have html formated text?

```
selectItems.AddRange(
  LoggedInUser.CategoriesUserCanAdminster.Select(x => new SelectListItem2()
  {
      Text = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("\xA0\xA0", x.Level + 1)) + x.Name,
      Value = x.Path,
      Selected = Model.Parent == x.Path,
      Disabled = !x.CanAdminister || x.Path.StartsWith(Model.Path)
  }
  ));
  }
@Html.DropDownList("Parent", selectItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: can you add a class to the `selectItems`?  If you can, just add a class where x.Level equals zero and then use that class to make it bold

Comment: Short answer - no its not possible using `DropDownList()` (and a dropdownlist is rendered by the operating system and only `background-color` and `color` can be applied anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change SelectListItem2 to be like follows

```
public class SelectListItem2
{
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
    public bool Disabled {get;set;}
    public bool Level0 {get;set;}
}
```

And then use a loop, and Html as follows

```
  <select>
    @foreach (SelectListItem2 item in selectItems)
    {
        if (item.Level0)
        {
            <option style="background-color:red" selected='@(item.Selected ? "selected" : "")' id="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option id="@item.Value" selected='@(item.Selected ? "selected" : "")'>@item.Text</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```