# ASP.NET How To Implement Auto-Complete Input on SelectList

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-select

I'm passing a SelectList of SelectListItems into a view using the ViewBag and am trying to implement an input with live filtering to search the items. I found out how to do this using **datalist** like this:

```
<input class="form-control" list="projectList" name="project" placeholder="Filter Projects"/>
<datalist id="projectList">
    @Html.DropDownList("projects", ViewBag.projects as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Project", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
</datalist>
```

which gives me the desired functionality with filtering:

[image: list example]

The problem is datalist can't be styled with CSS. Is there another way I can replicate this dropdown with filter on a passed in SelectList using something like jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: This could be an alternative solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411793/how-can-i-style-specific-item-in-a-mvc-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I have write a demo here can use css to change the dropdownlist style, I hope it can solve your problem.

**Html code**

```
<input  autocomplete="off" role="combobox" list="" id="input" name="browsers" placeholder="Select your fav browser">
  <!-- Its important that you keep list attribute empty to hide the default dropdown icon and the browser's default datalist -->

   <datalist id="browsers" role="listbox">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
    <option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option><option value="Microsoft Edge">Microsoft Edge</option>
    <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
  </datalist>
```

JavaScript

```
input.onfocus = function () {
    browsers.style.display = 'block';
    input.style.borderRadius = "5px 5px 0 0";  
  };
  for (let option of browsers.options) {
    option.onclick = function () {
      input.value = option.value;
      browsers.style.display = 'none';
      input.style.borderRadius = "5px";
    }
  };
  
  input.oninput = function() {
    currentFocus = -1;
    var text = input.value.toUpperCase();
    for (let option of browsers.options) {
      if(option.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(text) > -1){
        option.style.display = "block";
    }else{
      option.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
  }
  var currentFocus = -1;
  input.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
      currentFocus++
     addActive(browsers.options);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38){
      currentFocus--
     addActive(browsers.options);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 13){
      e.preventDefault();
          if (currentFocus > -1) {
            /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
            if (browsers.options) browsers.options[currentFocus].click();
          }
    }
  }
  
  function addActive(x) {
      if (!x) return false;
      removeActive(x);
      if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
      if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
      x[currentFocus].classList.add("active");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
```

**css**

```
input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: blue;
  /*   border-bottom: none; */
}
datalist {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-top: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 10rem;
  overflow-y: auto

}

option {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 4px;
  color: orangered;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

option:hover,  .active{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**result:**

[image]
[image]